# Either ran out or running out

Tags: usage

In the following sentence either **ran out** should be used or **was running out**

> US Secretary of State made it clear that time __________ for diplomacy over Iran's nuclear program and said that talks aimed at preventing Tehran from acquiring a nuclear weapon would resume in April.

I think it should be **ran out** because it would be better to say **the time duration of the talks was over and talks would resume in April**

But the answer in my book is **was running out**

Comment: The book's answer is correct because time has not run out – the talks will resume in April, in the hope of obtaining a solution through diplomacy. There could be any number of reasons why the talks have been deferred.

Comment: Agreed with the above. Also, not that you could have known, but "time was running out" is a really common phrase in English. "Time ran out" is correct but much less common — someone would probably say "time had run out" if they were talking about the past. No idea why.

Answer (score 2):

"Diplomacy", especially used without any modifier, is *general*. It can refer to all possible diplomatic actions in the past or future, not just the talks referred to. So it can't refer to "the particular talks that are over" as opposed to "talks in the future". For that, you'd need to say something like "the previous diplomacy" (but I wouldn't suggest that exact phrase as it seems odd to me).

Since they state that there will be more diplomatic talks in the future, that indicates there's still more time for diplomacy, and as a result time for *diplomacy in general* must not have run out.

Note that even if it only referred to the talks, they did not say that the talks were over. When something is over, it does not get resumed.

Comment: Perhaps ‘the previous round of talks’ instead of ‘the previous diplomacy’.

Answer (score 1):

*Was running out* is correct because of the word *would* here:

> talks ... would resume in April.

*Would* implies this could be backtracked.

If this text was

> talks ... *will* resume in April.

this would mean they've made their decision and therefore time *ran out*.